# How to convert cardinal to unsigned string representation

Tags: delphi

I have a dll routine that returns a UInt32. I gather that the Delphi cardinal type is equivalent to this type. I'd like to display the UInt32 value as a string. However inttostr () assumes the argument is a signed Int32 so it will sometimes return a string that has the appearance of a negative value. Is there a way to convert a cardinal into its unsigned string representation?

Using XE6.

Comment: Is there not UintToStr?

Comment: Which Delphi are you using?

Comment: Didn't spot uinttostr, and I've been looking...and it worked.

Comment: Good, you can make that an answer.

Comment: `IntToStr()` has an `Int64` version, not just an `Integer` version. Also, Delphi 2009 and later have an actual `UInt32` type, you should use that instead of `Cardinal`.

Answer (score 8):

To convert a UInt32 integer type into the unsigned string equivalent use the method [`UIntToStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.UIntToStr).

For example:

```
value : UInt32;

value := 4294967294;
str := UIntToStr (value);
// str now equals '4294967294'
```

Comment: `UInt32` and `UIntToStr()` were introduced in Delphi 2009 (yes, I see the OP is using XE6). FWIW, in earlier versions, you can pass a `Cardinal` to the `Int64` version of `IntToStr()` instead: `value: Cardinal; ... str := IntToStr(Int64(value));`.